# Which method does OpenFoam use to calculate the pressure and correct the velocities?

Tags: openfoam, pressure

I'm trying to run the case "cavity" but I've assigned a Dirichlet condition on the moving wall (p = 0) and I've noticed the pressure values change depending on the number of nodes (but I'm not quite sure yet). However, I would like to see the algorithm OpenFOAM uses to perform the velocity correction in order to ensure the incompressibility condition.

Does anyone have documentation about this algorithm? or do you know where in the libraries of OpenFoam could I get a better idea of which it's done internally?
I know it's the PISO method but I'd like more details.

Comment: Do u mean pimpleFoam? It is not clear which algorithm you ask about.

Comment: Well, actually any algorithm to calculate the pressure would be useful for me

Comment: The details are in the source code for the solver you choose. For example, this annotated version of the source code for [icoFoam](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/IcoFoam) (and the cited references) should provide the details you seek.